# How do I use an Azure DevOps Services Build Pipeline to retrieve TFVC source files based upon a Label value and then zip those files?

Tags: azure-devops, label, pipeline, tfvc

This is a TFVC repo in Azure, not Git.  It is running in Azure DevOps Services, not local in Azure DevOps Server (2019).  This is a classic pipeline, not YAML.
I got as far as adding a variable that contains the Label value I am looking to package into the zip file.
I can't figure out how to get the sources by Label value.  In the Pipeline Get Sources step, I've narrowed the path down, but then I need to recursively get source files that have the Label in the variable I defined.
The next step is to zip those source files up, I've added an Archive task to which I will change the root folder from "build binaries" to the sources folder.
This is necessary for this particular project because we must pass the source files to the vendor as a zip for them to compile and install for us.  The developers create/update the source files, build and test them locally, then apply a Label to the sources for a given push to the vendor.

Comment: Hi @GaryH, how are things going? Have you tried the suggestion in my answer? Is it helpful to you?

Answer (score 0):

When configuring '**Get sources**' step, there is no any option or method that can only map the source files with the specified label.

As a workaround, in the pipeline job, you can try to add the steps to filter out the source files with the specified label, and use the [**Copy Files task**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/copy-files?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) to copy these files to a folder, then use the [**Archive Files task**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/archive-files?view=azure-devops) in this folder.

**[UPDATE]**

Normally, a pipeline run will automatically check out the file version (**changeset**) that triggers the run. If manually trigger the the pipeline, by default the run will check out the latest **changeset** if you do not specify one.

The labels are used to mark a version of a files or folders, so you also can get the specific version of files or folders via the labels.

In your case, you can try using the '[**tf get**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/get-command?view=azure-devops)' command to download the files with the specified labels.

Comment: Bright Ran, Thank you.  I'll try this out on Monday. Appreciated!

Comment: It's okay. Any progress, feel free to tell me.

Comment: Bright Ran, working on it again this morning.  I am having difficulty figuring out how to use the Label with the Copy Files task.  Our labels are applied at the file level.  So labeled files may be spread across up to 4 folders currently.  Further background: this is not for our Microsoft Custom Applications group that uses branching for "normal" microsoft style builds.  The part I am doing is for an Oracle Forms development group that is not yet using work items or branching.  Just updating files in place.  Hence the labels to flag a version of a file.

Comment: Hi @GaryH, I have updated my answer with more suggestions. Please check it.

Comment: Bright Ran, Thank you again!  :-)  I am trying this out now.  Hopefully the Copy Files task supports version spec in the file naming.  If not, the other thought is to create a build only user with a workspace that gets wiped, uses a tf get by label to put files into it, then those files for specific changesets are sent to the archive folder for zipping.  Process repeated for next Label value.